# When calling a method between fragments, must it go through an activity?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-dialogfragment

I want to open a `dialog fragment` from `A fragment`, and pass data to A fragment when the dialog fragment ends.

To do this, I defined an interface in the dialog fragment and implemented it in the A fragment.

The result was that the listener was null.

This is because `onAttach()` used `context` and context meant `activity`.

The activity did not implement the interface.

Of course, it might have been nice to implement the interface in the activity, but I didn't want it because the method role didn't match the activity.

Is there no way?

***WriteRoutineFragment.java (A Fragment)***

```
public class WriteRoutineFragment extends Fragment implements 
        WorkoutListDialogFragment.OnAddRoutineListener {

    RecyclerView routine_rv;
    List<RoutineModel> items;
    List<String> titleData;
    RoutineListAdapter listAdapter;


    public static WriteRoutineFragment newInstance(Bundle data) {
        WriteRoutineFragment f = new WriteRoutineFragment();
        f.setArguments(data);
        return f;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ViewGroup rootView = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_write_routine, container, false);

        titleData = getArguments().getStringArrayList("title");
        listAdapter = new RoutineListAdapter(diffUtil2);
        items = new ArrayList<>();
//        routineAdapter = new RoutineAdapter();
        routine_rv.setAdapter(listAdapter);

        // ADD Routine
        listAdapter.setOnAddRoutineClickListener(new RoutineListAdapter.OnAddRoutineClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAddRoutineClick() {
                WorkoutListDialogFragment routineDialog = new WorkoutListDialogFragment();
                routineDialog.show(getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager(), "RoutineListDialog");
            }
        });

        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onAddRoutine(String routine) {
        RoutineModel routineModel = new RoutineModel(routine);
        RoutineDetailModel routineDetailModel = new RoutineDetailModel();
        routineModel.addDetail(routineDetailModel);

        items.add(routineModel);
        List<Object> list = getUpdatedList();
        listAdapter.submitList(list);
    }
}
```

***DialogFragment.java***

```
public class WorkoutListDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {
    static final String TAG = "RoutineListDialog";
    WorkoutListAdapter workoutListAdapter;
    OnAddRoutineListener listener;
    
    public interface OnAddRoutineListener {
        public void onAddRoutine(String routine);
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(@NonNull Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        if(context != null && context instanceof OnAddRoutineListener) {
            listener = (OnAddRoutineListener) context; // null
        }
        return;
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_workout_list_dialog, container, false);
        routineListRecycler = view.findViewById(R.id.routine_list_recycler);
        rountineChipGroup = view.findViewById(R.id.routine_chipgroup);

        workoutListAdapter.setOnWorkoutListClickListener(new WorkoutListAdapter.OnWorkoutListItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void OnItemClick(String routine) {
                if(listener != null) {
                    listener.onAddRoutine(routine);
                    dismiss();
                }
            }
        });
        return view;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why don't you use Live Data along with View Model ? If you wish to use them to handle this issue, please check my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To handle this kind of problem **Live Data** comes to play. By using Live Data we can pass data between fragments with out any issue. Just create a **View Model** like below:

```
    public class RoutineViewModel extends ViewModel {

    private MutableLiveData<String> mRoutine;

    public RoutineViewModel() {
        mRoutine = new MutableLiveData();
    }
    public void setRoutine(String data){
        mRoutine.setValue(data);
    }

    public LiveData<String> getRoutine(){ return mRoutine;}
}
```

And use this `View Model` in both the fragments in order to get the latest updated value of `Live Data`.

Using `View Model` and `Live Data` in **WriteRoutineFragment** looks like below:

```
private RoutineViewModel routineViewModel;

public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater,
                         ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    routineViewModel =
            new ViewModelProvider(requireActivity()).get(RoutineViewModel.class);
    View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);

    routineViewModel.getRoutine().observe(getViewLifecycleOwner(), new Observer<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged(String s) {
            Log.d("TAG==>>","Routine changed = "+s);
        }
    });
    listAdapter.setOnAddRoutineClickListener(new RoutineListAdapter.OnAddRoutineClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAddRoutineClick() {
            WorkoutListDialogFragment routineDialog = new WorkoutListDialogFragment();
            routineDialog.show(getChildFragmentManager(), "RoutineListDialog");
        }
    });

    return root;
}
```

Using `View Model` and `Live Data` in **WorkoutListDialogFragment** looks like below:

```
    public class WorkoutListDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {
    private RoutineViewModel routineViewModel;
    WorkoutListAdapter workoutListAdapter; 
    public WorkoutListDialogFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        routineViewModel =
                new ViewModelProvider(requireActivity()).get(RoutineViewModel.class);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_workout_list_dialog, container, false);
    }
    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, Bundle savedInstanceState){
        workoutListAdapter.setOnWorkoutListClickListener(new WorkoutListAdapter.OnWorkoutListItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void OnItemClick(String routine) {
                routineViewModel.setRoutine(routine);
                dismiss();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. But I'll ask you a question. I heard about a design pattern called `MVVM`, and I heard that it is used a lot in android these days.

I also looked for it to learn this for the first time, but it was unfamiliar and it was very difficult, so I delayed learning for a while. I'm a beginner...

But even if I don't use the `MVVM` pattern, can I just use the ViewModel for data sharing? I am not very good at designing MVVM.

Comment: See MVVM is the architecture of your project. If you use MVVM then it will be easier for you to maintain large projects. You can use ViewModel and LiveData. ViewModel and LiveData are libraries but MVVM is not a library rather it's just a design pattern.

Comment: By the way, MVVM is not just using ViewModel and LiveData, but shouldn't I create a project structurally?

I think it's difficult. Isn't it simple to use ViewModel and LiveDaata?

Comment: Oh, in addition, it seems to be different from MVVM's view model and ViewModel class, right? The ViewModel class seems to refer to a ViewModel of something called AAC.I thought the view model of MVVM is the ViewModel class

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager()` use `getChildFragmentManager()` while showing dialog, now the context will tied to fragment and the listener won’t be null

```
listAdapter.setOnAddRoutineClickListener(new RoutineListAdapter.OnAddRoutineClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAddRoutineClick() {
            WorkoutListDialogFragment routineDialog = new WorkoutListDialogFragment();
            routineDialog.show(getChildFragmentManager(), "RoutineListDialog");
        }
    });
```